# Can't weight paint in Blender 2.92.0 (Rigify)

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I've been wracking my brain around this watching tons of tutorials and trying different ways of getting weight painting to work. I've done Pose Mode or Edit Mode > Weight Paint when clicking my armature rig then my mesh, but no weights appear and can't click on any bones or joints in this mode. Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know what the issue is? https://drive.google.com/file/d/16PFcQZZeyKn1FO2DkxGzlCQIG-J-938M/view?usp=sharing this is a link to my blender project if that helps at all if my setup is wrong.

Thanks for any help!

[image: Blender Workspace Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected the *Select Box* tool It's highlighted in Blue on your toolbar.
Select the top tool, the brush.

But you have also selected *Paint Mask* It's highlighted in blue in the header. Deselect it and you'll be able to paint

[image: Header, showing that Paint Mask is selected.]

Comment: Ahhhh thanks so much! Saved me a massive headache haha.